# Nested models issue in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-activerecord

Suppose I have three models, `Campaign`, created by an owner `User`, and with lots of members (who are users) represented by `Membership`.

The first Campaign is set with this statement

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships
```

the second User with this statement

```
has_many :memberships
has_many :campaigns, :through => :memberships
```

the third Membership

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :campaign
```

Now I want to define a nested forms when a campaign is created, allowing the campaign creator to choose among all users, some members of his campaign. So I set

```
= form_for @campaign do |f|
    = f.text_field :owner, placeholder: "Example Owner", class: "xxlarge"
    - @users.each_value do |value|
        = f.fields_for :memberships do |ff|
            = ff.check_box :user_id
```

where `@users` is set in the `new` method of the `Campaign` controller as so

```
@users = User.all
```

The problem is that I have an error message

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 113ms

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal.):
    20:       = f.text_field :owner, placeholder: "Example Owner", class: "xxlarge"
    21: 
    22:   @users.each_value do |value|
    23:     = f.fields_for :memberships do |ff|
    24:         = ff.check_box :user_id
```

I am quite new to rails and I don't understand where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to place a `-` in front of the `@users.each_value` to evaluate the code?

Comment: Sorry I mistook when I copy paste my post

Comment: @Newben I don't think you did, given the error has the same 'mistake' in it.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I replaced `@users.each_value` by `@users.each` and it worked just fine